# How to align latex tables when using macro folding

Tags: latex, code-folding, align, table

I have a latex table which contains some long commands like includegraphics or href which makes the table very nasty to read.

To get a better view I fold all macros in the table and want to use `align-current`. However this doesn't work as expected as in the following MWE-screencast:

[image]

Align per se works as you can see in this demo:

[image]

How can I fix this? Is there a better way to get a nice few of my table?

The `latex-fold-macros` macro I use above is defined as follows:

```
(defun latex-fold-macros ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((macro (read-from-minibuffer "Macro: ")))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (search-forward (format "%s" macro) nil t)
    (TeX-fold-macro)
    )
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: You might get a better response if you post the code you're working on.  No one wants to write all that out.